# Menu container div fade in/out not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, function

I am working on a torrent page and I tried to implement div container fade-in/fade-out style using js. But the code isn't working for some reason, and also in the console there is no error log. 
Below is my codes:

HTML:

```
<div class="cover-container d-flex w-100 h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
      <header class="masthead mb-auto">
        <div class="inner">
          <h3 class="masthead-brand">Torrents.ServerClouD</h3>
          <nav class="nav nav-masthead justify-content-center">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="home" href="index.php">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link" id="torrents">Completed Torrents</a>
            <a class="nav-link" id="contact">Contact</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>

      <div class="main" id="home-container">
      <main role="main" class="inner cover">
        <h1 class="cover-heading">Upload your .torrent file</h1>
        <p class="lead">Magnet Link support is currently in development and will be available soon.</p>
        <p class="lead">
       <form name="frm" action="reciever.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="completeAndRedirect();"> 
          Filename: <br> <input  id="file" name="file" type="file" accept=".torrent" /> <br><br> 
          <input type="submit" name="Upload" value="Submit" /> 
    </form>
        </p>
      </main>
      </div>

      <div class="main" id="torrents-container" style="display:none">
      <h2>Here is the link for torrents which have downloaded / leeched completely.</h2>
        <input type="submit" value="Click Me!" name="DoneTorrents" onclick="window.open('https://servercd.tk')"  style="height:50px; width:80px" />
      </div>

      <div class="main" id="contact-container" style="display:none">
      <p>Please contact us at blahblahblahblah</p>
      </div>
```

JS:

```
 $('#home').click(function(e){    
    $('#home-container, #torrents-container, #contact-container').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#home-container').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});

  $('#torrents').click(function(e){    
       $('#home-container, #torrents-container, #contact-container').fadeOut('slow', function(){
           $('#torrents-container').fadeIn('slow');
       });
   });

    $('#contact').click(function(e){    
         $('#home-container, #torrents-container, #contact-container').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#contact-container').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });

function completeAndRedirect(){

        var input= document.forms['frm'].file.name;
            if(input==null) {
                alert("please upload first!");
            }else{
               //var t = alert('Please wait while Uploading...');
                $unicode = iconv("utf-8","cp936","name");
                location.href='reviever.php';

                }
            }
```

I know there must have been an error, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: If you can make a working example in jsfiddle or something then it would be very easy to find the issue.

Comment: It was taken from a working jsfiddle sample, just have some changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting multiple ids will work but `fadeOut` needs to be applied individually.

```
$("#home-container, #torrents-container, #contact-container").each(
  function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('slow')
  })
```

and this function will have to be implemented separately.

```
 $('#home-container').fadeIn('slow');
```

assuming you want it to be fadein after everything has faded out

$('#contact').click(function(e){

```
var items = $("#home-container, #torrents-container, #contact-container");
```

items.fadeOut("slow")

```
$('#contact-container').fadeIn('slow'); 

});
```

Comment: `$('#contact').click(function(e){    
   $("#home-container, #torrents-container, #contact-container").each( function() {  $(this).fadeOut('slow')； });
   $('#contact-container').fadeIn('slow');
    });` This?

Comment: just added my code in an edit. , each is asynchronous , so this is easier , but there may be ways to promise which would work after each has finished

Comment: i have a plunk of your code it seems to work without needing my code added https://plnkr.co/edit/kUCsoVq33Xt9zrqpe6Ts?p=preview
the only thing it lacked was jquery if you can show the original page where the problem is may be i can help a bit more

Comment: you are using jquery slim , not the entire jquery "Alongside the standard jQuery, the slim version excludes ajax, effects, and currently deprecated code, coming in at a svelte 23.6k vs the full version's 30k. ... Among the new features in the 3.0 major milestone, anticipated since October 2014, is an updated jQuery.Deferred objects."

and fades are effects replace with full jquery or customise so fade effect comes in

Comment: there are two versions of jquery loading , you need to use other jquery or replace the slim one with full one ,

Comment: another option is var jQuery3 = $.noConflict(true); (in your main js)and then replace all $ with jQuery to make this work (but this forces $ to be jquery 1.8.3 and not the newer slim version)

Comment: if this works please select the answer and lets close this post set

Comment: I switch to the latest 3.3.1 version jquery and tried old version code and your code. Mine still not working, and using the "for(i=0)" it got "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".

Comment: sorry my code did not look correct i formatted it use that code now

Comment: No problem , mark as answer and lets close the post